# How to find the next Double in Java or Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, numbers, double

When having a Double d, I'd like to know which Double' is the smalles possible value bigger than d.

When d==0 I know the answer, that will be Double.MIN_VALUE :

```
> 0d + Double.MIN_VALUE
4.9E-324
```

But what about all ohter numbers like for instance 1d ?

```
> 1d + Double.MIN_VALUE
1.0
```

It has to do wit significant numbers I guess, but in short : I'm looking for a method that gives me the next double

```
nextDouble(0)==4.9E-324
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is easy. Positive double's are ordered at bit level just the way longs are. So converting it to a long and increasing it and then back to a double does the trick:

```
public static double nextDouble(double d)
{
    if (d != d) return d;
    if (d == Double.MAX_VALUE) return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    if (d == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) return d;
    if (d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) return d;

    d += 0.0;
    int dir = d < 0.0 ? -1 : 1; 
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(d) + dir);
}
```

The same works for negative values. If you want to get the closest double that is bigger, then decrease the long representation.

In response to the alternative `Math.nextUp()`, here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FpUtils.java#FpUtils.nextUp%28double%29) for that method:

```
public static double nextUp(double d) {
    if( isNaN(d) || d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
        return d;
    else {
        d += 0.0d;
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) +
                                       ((d >= 0.0d)?+1L:-1L));
    }
}
```

This is equivalent with my code, that does the extra checks for infinity.

Comment: While clever, that has a very nasty boundary case. However, a few masks and tests and it will work. -1 becomes +1 if you take the time to show those.

Comment: I was actually thinking of carry from mantissa to exponent, but after thinking some more, it might actually work. So +1.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux : your previous version was better IMHO

Comment: @Peter: I know. I was confused for a little while. Did an immediate rollback :)

Comment: No , I mean just the oneliner

Comment: @kdgregory: If the mantisse overflows, it increases the exponent, which is exactly what we want. In binary: 1.11111111111... is equal to 10.

Comment: double min value has a next double, and I much prefer values as infinity or NaN that I can test on than just back the original number

Comment: @Peter: Good point. I updated the code. I don't really understand your second comment?

Comment: Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.MAX_VALUE) + 1) yields --> Infinity , that was ok for me

Comment: What is the advantage of this over Math.nextUp, which seems simpler to use?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: None, I guess. I simply wasn't aware of the built-in function. Check my update.

Comment: `d += 0.0;` seems to do exactly nothing. Why is it there?

Comment: @AlexanderKosenkov It's there to convert -0.0 into +0.0. If it was not there, then the next up for -0.0 would be -Double.MIN_VALUE, instead of Double.MIN_VALUE, because `d >= 0.0d` is still true for -0.0

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at these functions.

[`public static double nextAfter(double start, double direction)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter%28double,%20double%29)

> Returns the floating-point number adjacent to the first argument in
>   the direction of the second argument. If both arguments compare as
>   equal the second argument is returned.

[`public static double nextUp(double d)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp%28double%29)

> Returns the floating-point value adjacent to d in the direction of
>   positive infinity. This method is semantically equivalent to
>   `nextAfter(d, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);` however, a nextUp
>   implementation may run faster than its equivalent nextAfter call.

Comment: IMHO: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Do it this way:

```
Double d = Math.random();
Double next = d + Math.ulp(d);
```

From the JavaDoc:

> An ulp of a double value is the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude.

Comment: You should accept the answer **You** think is the right one, which answers your question best.