# How to get nearest value representable by a floating-point number?

Tags: floating-point, precision

I have a single precision floating point number which equals, say, to:

```
0.999989986419677734375 (decimal)
00111111011111111111111101011000 (binary)
```

I need to find the next discrete value that is bigger than this value. This must exactly be the next least possible value that can be represented by my float type. No other values should be able to be represented in between these values because of the precision limitation of the floating point storage.

How can I calculate such a number?

Comment: Look for nextUp.  There are answers like https://stackoverflow.com/q/1245870/217324 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/22715536/217324

Comment: Thank you, I have just been googling it wrong.